# Wrong MySQL subquery count comparison result

Tags: mysql, sql

So I found a bug in my application, it wasn't showing me a result it should have. I traced it back to the following SQL query (I removed the irrelevant parts).

As you can see the query selects rows from `wc_hncat_products` of which the corresponding id's have a count of >= 1 inside the `wc_hncat_product_category_has_product` table

If I execute the query with the subquery result as a column, you can see the result is `1`. But when I use it in the WHERE clause the `>= 1` comparison fails.

Proof that the subquery DOES return 1:
[image: Proof that the subquery DOES return 1]

```
SELECT `wc_hncat_products`.`id`, 
   (SELECT Count(*) 
    FROM   `wc_hncat_product_categories` 
           INNER JOIN `wc_hncat_product_category_has_product` 
                   ON `wc_hncat_product_categories`.`id` = 
                      `wc_hncat_product_category_has_product`.`category_id` 
    WHERE  `wc_hncat_product_category_has_product`.`product_id` = 
           `wc_hncat_products`.`id` 
           AND `category_id` IN ( '1' )) count 
FROM   `wc_hncat_products` 
WHERE  `id` IN ( '785' )
```

This query returns one row, with the column `count` value being 1

No results with subquery count comparison in WHERE clause
[image: No results with subquery count comparison in WHERE clause]

```
SELECT `wc_hncat_products`.`id` 
FROM   `wc_hncat_products` 
WHERE  (SELECT Count(*) 
        FROM   `wc_hncat_product_categories` 
           INNER JOIN `wc_hncat_product_category_has_product` 
                   ON `wc_hncat_product_categories`.`id` = 
                                      `wc_hncat_product_category_has_product`.`category_id` 
            WHERE  `wc_hncat_product_category_has_product`.`product_id` = 
           `wc_hncat_products`.`id` 
           AND `category_id` IN ( '1' )) >= 1 
   AND `id` IN ( '785' )
```

This query selects 0 rows..

How is this possible? You can see the count actually is 1, but the comparison still fails as no results are being returned while the subqueries are identical in both scenarios.

Comment: I can't read those small picture texts.

Comment: Edit your question and past the queries in the question as *text*.  You have enough experience on the site that you should know this is a good idea.

Comment: I updated the question to include the code blocks.

Comment: What version of MySQL are you using? What data type are the `category_id` and `id` columns in your query?

Comment: Mysql version is 5.7.16 and both those columns are INT, but when I remove the single quotes around `1` and `785` nothing changes

Answer (score 0):

The standard way to implement that type of check is to use [`EXISTS`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/exists-and-not-exists-subqueries.html).

Something like this should work for you:

```
SELECT `wc_hncat_products`.`id` 
FROM   `wc_hncat_products` 
WHERE  EXISTS (SELECT NULL 
        FROM   `wc_hncat_product_categories` 
           INNER JOIN `wc_hncat_product_category_has_product` 
                   ON `wc_hncat_product_categories`.`id` = 
                                      `wc_hncat_product_category_has_product`.`category_id` 
            WHERE  `wc_hncat_product_category_has_product`.`product_id` = 
           `wc_hncat_products`.`id` 
           AND `category_id` IN ( '1' )) 
   AND `id` IN ( '785' )
```

Comment: This still gives me no results when I put it in the `WHERE` clause, it does however give me a result when I use the same subquery in the `SELECT` clause like so `SELECT \`wc_hncat_products\`.\`id\`,  (SELECT \`category_id\` ...) as test`

Comment: Another option is that you can rewrite the query to remove the sub-query entirely, and instead join `wc_hncat_products` to  `wc_hncat_product_categories` and `wc_hncat_product_category_has_product`, and that your `SELECT` clause to `SELECT DISTINCT` to avoid returning duplicate products.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion but I'm looking for an explanation why the queries aren't working. I really don't get why they don't work. Maybe it has something to do with some mysql or engine setting.

Comment: Did you paste the entire query in your question? You said you "removed the irrelevant parts", so it's possible that the problem involves part of the query that you didn't show us.

Comment: I indeed removed some irrelevant parts but did test if the problem persisted after removing those parts, and it did.